# MySQLi insert statement to executing

Tags: php, mysqli

I am writing a simple code in PHP to test my MySql server by , inserting data to my database server

i am executing the file from the internet

URL of executing : `Scores2.php?n=asdad&l=345&s=241`

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$servername = "sql3.freesqldatabase.com";
$username = "MY USERNAME";
$password = "MY PASSWORD";
$dbname = "MY DBNAME";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$name = (string)$_GET['n'];
$score = (int)$_GET['s'];
$level = (int)$_GET['l'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO HighScores (name, score, level)
VALUES ($name, $score, $level)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

When i execute the file , the browser shows this error  :

```
Error: INSERT INTO HighScores (name, score, level) VALUES (asdad, 241, 345)
Unknown column 'asdad' in 'field list'
```

I checked the **Control Panel** in **phpMyAdmin** and executed the same statement but without variables , and it worked

**Rows Types :**

name : text

score : int(11)

level : int (11)

Comment: $name needs to be wrapped in " or ' so do like this '$name'

Comment: Should use prepared statements

Answer (score 2):

- Learn how to [prepare the query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) it's not that difficult.
- You will avoid sql injection and missing quotes
- Use `num_rows` to check if the record is inserted
- Use `$conn->error` if the `prepare()` call return false.

```
$name = (string)$_GET['n'];
$score = (int)$_GET['s'];
$level = (int)$_GET['l'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO HighScores (name, score, level)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)";


if ($stmt = $conn ->prepare($sql)) {

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $score);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $level);

    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }else{
        echo "no rows affected"; 
    }

    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn ->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO HighScores (name, score, level)
VALUES ('$name', '$score', '$level')";
```

change query like this